# Post запрос для регистрации. Андроид

Tags: android, post, регистрация

Прошу совета в следующем вопросе.
Нужно реализовать регистрацию пользователя. Решил попробовать библиотеку Retrofit, но приложение упало.

P.S: строго не судите, я новичек)
Вот код

```
private static final Gson GSON = new GsonBuilder().setPrettyPrinting().create();
    private static final String TAG = "this";
    private final String baseUrl = "http://u1938.blue.elastictech.org/api/users";

    private Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().create();
    private Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))
            .baseUrl(baseUrl)
            .build();

    private Link parse = (Link) retrofit.create(List.class);


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.registration_activity);

        Intent intent = getIntent();
        intent.getExtras();

        buttonRegistration2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                if (editPassword != editPassword2) {
                    Toast.makeText(RegistrationActivity.this, "Пароли не совпадают. Повторите попытку", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                else {
                    Map<String, String> mapJson = new HashMap<String, String>();
                    mapJson.put("email", editEmail.getText().toString());
                    mapJson.put("name", editUserName.getText().toString());
                    mapJson.put("password", editPassword.getText().toString());
                    mapJson.put("contact_number", editNumber.getText().toString());

                    Call<Object> call = parse.parseMethod(mapJson);

                    try {
                        Response<Object> response = call.execute();
                        Map<String, String> map = gson.fromJson(response.body().toString(), Map.class);

                        for (Map.Entry e : map.entrySet())
                        {
                            System.out.println(e.getKey() + "" + e.getValue());
                            Log.e(TAG, "Object");
                        }
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }

            }
        });
    }
```

Интерфейс

```
interface Link {
    @FormUrlEncoded
    @POST("/users")
    Call<Object> parseMethod(@FieldMap Map<String, String> map);
}
```

Ошибка

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.example.idrisov.mypost/com.example.idrisov.mypost.RegistrationActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.Window$Callback android.view.Window.getCallback()' on a null object reference
                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2849)
```

Answer (score 0):

Вы забыли в `onCreate` проинициализировать переменную `buttonRegistration2` после `setContentView(R.layout.registration_activity);`

Добавьте `buttonRegistration2 = findViewById(R.id.your_buttton_id);`, где `your_buttton_id` - id, указанный для кнопки в `registration_activity.xml`